# How to disable switched outlet

Tags: electrical

I did search for existing questions regarding this subject. However, I think this situation is a little different. Let me first explain that I know next to nothing about wiring when it becomes a little complicated.
I have a room with 4 outlets. 2 of them are switched (up/down). I would like to disable one of the switched outlets which I think is in the middle of the run and comes after the switched outlet I want to leave as is. The switch only controls those 2 outlets and is one of 3 switches in the box. Attached are pictures of the switch and outlet. Thank you in advance for your advice.

10/30/22 Let me expand on my initial post. First I'm attaching another picture of the switch to show the wiring again, one wire coming in and the red one going out. That everything looks white is because when a house is build here (USA) they spraypaint the sheetrock. No holes have been drilled in the box that I can see. The black wire goes to the red wire nut.
Also to be more clear in what I'm trying to accomplish is I want that particular double outlet to be always hot.[image: 2-wires-to-another shot switch]

[image: Switched outlet]

[image: Switch]

Comment: Show the side of the outlet with the black wires, please.

Comment: Clarification: when you write that you want to "disable one of the switched outlets" - I assume you want to make it non-switched and always on, rather than actually disable it and make it non-functional ... ?

Comment: What country is this? Doesn't really look like something that would still be approved.

Comment: FYI- [This](https://imgur.com/a/5gmLFSU) appears to be a non-code compliant modification to the box. I'm not sure why ground wires seem to exit the box on their own (i.e. not in conjunction with the cables in the box), but drilling holes in plastic boxen isn't, to my knowledge, permitted.

Comment: Based on the boxes, wire nuts, wire colors and cables in the pics, @PMF, I'd put a _very_ high likelihood on this being in the USA.

Comment: Also using the backstabs? You may wish to move all of those to the screws as you are changing things around.

Comment: Please clarify, do you have four duplex outlets such as the one in your picture, that accommodate a total of eight devices and two of those outlets, in two locations are switched, and you've included a photo of one?  *Or* do you have two duplex outlets, one of them (with two receptacles) is switched, and this photo is of THAT one? Or is it of the unswitched one?  What do you mean by "is in the middle of the run and comes after"?  That seems to be contradictory.

Comment: My apologies I'm not clear with my question. In that room are 5 outlets (duplex). 2 of them are switched. I want one of them to be always hot. If I go around the room the outlets (both) are not directly located next to the switch. So I assume that they are all on the same circuit, but only 2 are switched. As I mentioned before, I'm very much of a beginner when it comes to wiring.

Comment: @FreeMan That’s not a drilled hole, it’s a crimp connection joining ground wires, floating in air (suspended by the solid wires). It’s like an uninsulated wire nut, but not removable.

Comment: wow, @nobody... I had to stare at that for a couple of minutes to figure out what you were seeing, but I do see it now.

Answer (score 1):

If one switch controls both outlets and you just one outlet to be controlled by the switch you will have to bypass one of the outlets altogether and segregate it from that switch. meaning run new line to the outlet for all intents and purposes. UNLESS both outlets run separately to the switch independent from one another. My guess is the switch is not inline with the outlet but the switch actually provides power to the outlets as in S - O - O vs O - S - O. If it were the latter you could just connect the wiring from off the switch for that one outlet but my guess is the outlets are daisy chained to one another.

Comment: If your solution is the only one available then I'm out of luck. Running a new line would mean going on the attic etc. Thanks for your suggestion but I'm hoping to get another one.

Comment: If you need an always on outlet, you need unswitched power at that outlet.  The only alternative I see is to keep the switch always on, and use home automation or similar to switch the outlets you do want to control.